# How to read XML String into List or any collection

Tags: c#, xml, linq, collections

I have string simillar to

```
xmlDataEntAddAttr = @"<ADDITIONAL INFO>
                            <Host> Test Host Name </Host>
                            <IP Address>Test IP Address</IP Address>
                            <Domain>Test Domain</Domain>
                            <Host Method>Test Host Method</Host Method>
                            <Flag>Test Flag</Flag>
                      </ADDITIONAL INFO>";
```

How can i read this into a String list with tag names and Values in it or in any collection.
Please not the inner Tags like `<Host></Host>` can be any value only constant thing here is the root means `<ADDITIONAL INFO></ADDITIONAL INFO>`.

Please suggest any method to parse.

Comment: What you do mean by a string list?  Do you want your list to 5 elements with the values of each 5 tag?  or do you want the Tags themselves too?  Specifically, I'm wondering if you want `<Host> Test Host Name </Host>` or `Test Host Name` in your list

Comment: @psubsee2003 I want both tag name `<Host></Host>` and tag value `Test Host Name` in list or any collection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `XDocument` (in the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace) and Linq to Xml.

```
XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlDataEntAddAttr);
Dictionary<string, string> result = xDocument.Root.Elements().ToDictionary(element => element.Name.LocalName, element => element.Value);
```

However, your string is not a valid XML. You can't have whitespace in the XML element names. A valid version of you string is:

```
xmlDataEntAddAttr = @"<ADDITIONAL_INFO>
                            <Host> Test Host Name </Host>
                            <IP_Address>Test IP Address</IP_Address>
                            <Domain>Test Domain</Domain>
                            <Host_Method>Test Host Method</Host_Method>
                            <Flag>Test Flag</Flag>
                      </ADDITIONAL_INFO>";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, This is exactly what i needed but is it possible to read the XML elements with space at all with any tweak as the data which is coming in XML string is difficult to change.

Comment: @Pratik If there are whitespaces in the element names, it is not called XML because it does not conform the XML specification. So unless you want to create your own corrupted-XML parser, I recommend you to fix the XML source.

Comment: Appreciate the comments Cedric creating a bad parser will be bad option. Will implement the change in XML elements itself. Many thanks for help

Comment: how is this called what you are using to pass parameters? => chained syntax or something like this? am i right that it's supposed to replace a foreach loop ?

Comment: This is called a lambda expression. And, indeed in this case, it replaces a foreach loop : `for (var element in xDocument.Root.Elements) dictionary.Add(element.Name.LocalName, element.Value)`

Answer (score 1):

If my xml is structured like the following:

```
<nodes>
    <node id="123">
        <text>text goes here</text>
    </node>
</nodes>
```

Then I could do this:

```
XDocument xDoc;
using(StringReader sr = new StringReader("thexml"))
{
    xDoc = XDocument.Load(sr);
}
myDictionary = xDoc.Descendants("node").ToDictionary(x => x.Attribute("id").Value, x =>         x.Descendants("text").First().Value);
```

Comment: Appriciate your help Will, but my solution is more close to Cedric's answer.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Note you need to remove the spaces in Additional Info, IP Address and Host Method

```
        var xmlDataEntAddAttr = @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
                        <ADDITIONALINFO>
                        <Host> Test Host Name </Host>
                        <IPAddress>Test IP Address</IPAddress>
                        <Domain>Test Domain</Domain>
                        <HostMethod>Test Host Method</HostMethod>
                        <Flag>Test Flag</Flag>
                  </ADDITIONALINFO>";
        var xDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlDataEntAddAttr);
        if (xDocument.Root != null)
        {
            var coll = xDocument.Root.Elements().Select(x => new {Name = x.Name, Value = x.Value});
            foreach (var item in coll)
            {
              Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}\tValue: {1}", item.Name, item.Value);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```